# JavaScript autocomplete without external library

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

Is there a javascript autocomplete library that does not depend on any other libraries?

I am not using jQuery or the likes as I am making a mobile app that I need to keep extra light.

Comment: http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/gr/column5/index.html

Comment: @PeterAjtai this link is broken.

Answer (score 35):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/StevenIseki/qo9yzj3r/) is a basic JavaScript example, which could be modified into an autocomplete control:

```js
var people = ['Steven', 'Sean', 'Stefan', 'Sam', 'Nathan'];

function matchPeople(input) {
  var reg = new RegExp(input.split('').join('\\w*').replace(/\W/, ""), 'i');
  return people.filter(function(person) {
    if (person.match(reg)) {
      return person;
    }
  });
}

function changeInput(val) {
  var autoCompleteResult = matchPeople(val);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = autoCompleteResult;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="changeInput(this.value)">
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: For the benefit of future readers, I have implemented a library just for this (http://github.com/uohzxela/fuzzy-autocomplete). It does depend on jQuery though. However a vanilla JS version is in the works.

Comment: Hey there! Really like your answer! 2 questions. 1 - Is it important, or necessary to cache  the compiled expression? I'm asking because of this article: http://www.dustindiaz.com/autocomplete-fuzzy-matching 2- How can I limit it to return x amount from the array?

Comment: replacing `.join('\\w*')` with `.join('\\w*\\s*\\w*')` will make it possible to match letters from different words

Comment: This sadly is an autosuggestion not a autocomplete. You can't choose the suggestion.

Comment: Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/heronils/pen/KxrZwN?editors=1010) loosely related to this code example. It uses jQuery to filter around 500 elements. Performs good. Should perform even better when using vanilla js.

Comment: But this matching is case sensitive. How can you make a matching case insensitive?

Comment: @P.Lorand .toLowerCase() should fix that

Comment: This concept is amazing, but using an HTML Dataset (which is supported by all browsers I believe) which automatically attaches to an input

Answer (score 31):

For anyone looking at this in 2017 onwards who needs a simple solution, you can use HTML5's built-in `<datalist>` tag instead of relying on JavaScript.

Example:

```
<datalist id="languages">
  <option value="HTML">
  <option value="CSS">
  <option value="JavaScript">
  <option value="Java">
  <option value="Ruby">
  <option value="PHP">
  <option value="Go">
  <option value="Erlang">
  <option value="Python">
  <option value="C">
  <option value="C#">
  <option value="C++">
</datalist>

<input type="text" list="languages">
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

Comment: I _imagine_ this would be faster than JS since it's a browser API. I haven't done any benchmarks though, which is what I'd recommend doing if you have very large data sets. I've only used this for small lists (200-300 items) that didn't need anything fancy (note that for a more complicated setup you'll want to use JavaScript or a combination of both).

Comment: As of April 20, 2021, the above example works in Safari too.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated accordingly by removing the line about Safari.

Answer (score 9):

The core of an autocomplete script will be the ajax call to the dictionary of terms.

I assume your mobile application already includes an ajax function, so maybe you're better off just writing your autocomplete from scratch? Basically all you need in an input tag, a keyup event handler that triggers the ajax call, and a div to collect the response.

[Update] Based on the comments, some references from John Resig's blog:

http://ejohn.org/blog/revised-javascript-dictionary-search/

http://ejohn.org/blog/jquery-livesearch/

Comment: I was planning to make the autocomplete work from a local dictionary, or a remote AJAX call, or a mixture of the two (so already used words are added to local dictionary from the remote call) or... to use the existing dictionary on the mobile device. I don't see the data source as the responsibility of the autocomplete script, but a separate issue. For me, the most complicated part of making my own, would be an efficient way to search an array of possible matches. I imagine some kind of b-tree algorithm, but would prefer to use well thought out code for this task rather than make my own.

Comment: ok, I see. If you use a remote call, the query will be handed over to the data source, not processed in the JavaScript code. If the dictionary is local, then I don't know (and I guess it would depend on your rule: match beginning, match any  part of the string?). I've been using several articles from John Resig's blog as reference to do such things, for example http://ejohn.org/blog/revised-javascript-dictionary-search/

Comment: I have edited my answer to add references. I am using the second one for local filtering.

Comment: I was reading those links earlier. The first is a jQuery dependent solution, so I skipped over it. The second is very interesting (and the two articles leading up to it) but unfortunately does not quite fit what I need because I must match the start of the word, and not the whole word. I might use it as a starting point for a home baked solution, as he has pretty much done all the benchmarking legwork to figure out what is efficient, and I probably would get away with minimal editing. Thanks for the research.

Comment: I ended up using the second link as a starting point for my own solution, which worked very efficiently - but is maybe currently lacking in functionality. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

ES2016 feature: `Array.prototype.includes` without external library.

```
function autoComplete(Arr, Input) {
    return Arr.filter(e =>e.toLowerCase().includes(Input.toLowerCase()));
}
```

[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/ronaldaug/pen/PyYmgx)

Comment: Hello @ronaldtgi,
IE 11 and earlier version does not support includes function as per information in "https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp"
So What can be used instead of includes?

Comment: Hi @AshishShah , alternatively, you can use **indexOf()** . 
e.g `function autoComplete(Arr, Input) {
    return Arr.filter(e=>e.toLowerCase().indexOf(Input.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
}`

Answer (score 1):

I was researching this the other night, and my solution was originally like the ES6 solution in here, like this:

```
return this.data.filter((option) => {
    return option.first_name
        .toString()
        .toLowerCase()
        .indexOf(this.searchTerms.toLowerCase()) >= 0
})
```

But the problem with that is it isn't robust enough to handle filtering nested data. You can see it is filtering `this.data` which has a data structure like:

```
[
    { first_name: 'Bob', },
    { first_name: 'Sally', },
]
```

You can see it filters based on `this.searchTerms` after lowercasing both the search term and `option.first_name`, but it is too rigid to search for `option.user.first_name`. My original attempt was to pass in the field to filter by, such as:

```
this.field = 'user.first_name';
```

But this involves savage, custom JavaScript to handle something like `this.field.split('.')` and dynamically generating the filter function.

Instead, I remembered an old library I've used before called `fuse.js`, and it is working well because it not only handles that case of arbitrary nesting on what I just called `this.field` but also handles fuzzy matching based on defined thresholds.

Check out here: https://fusejs.io/

[edit note]: I realize this question is looking for no-external-library, but I want to keep this post here as it provides adjacent value. It is not intended to be "the" solution.

Here is how I'm currently using it:

```
import Fuse from 'fuse.js';

const options = {
    threshold: 0.3,
    minMatchCharLength: 2,
    keys: [this.field],
};

const fuse = new Fuse(this.data, options);

this.filteredData = fuse.search(this.searchTerms);
```

You will have to read the Fuse docs to understand that better, but fundamentally, you can see that a `new Fuse()` object is created using the data to filter and the options.

The `keys: [this.field]` part is important because that's where you pass in the keys to search by, and you can pass in an array of them. For example, you could filter `this.data` by `keys: ['user.first_name', 'user.friends.first_name']`.

I am using this currently in Vue JS, so I have that above logic inside an instance `watch` function, so every time `this.searchTerms` changes, that logic runs and updates `this.filteredData` which is placed into my dropdown list in my autocomplete component.

Also I'm sorry I just realized this question specifically says without an external library, but I'll post this anyway because I find this question every time I make an ES6 autocomplete in Vue JS or React JS. I think it is very valuable to have strict or loose fuzzy matching and to support arbitrarily nested data. Based on Webpack bundle analyzer, `fuse.js` is 4.1kb gzipped, so it is quite small given that it can support "all" client-side filtering needs.

If you are limited in your ability to use external libraries, consider my first example piece of code. It works if your data structure is static, and you can easily change `option.first_name` to something like `option[this.field]` if you wish to variablize the searched field (ie: if your objects are always flat).

You could variablize the list to search as well. Try something like this:

```
const radicalFilter = ({ collection, field, searchTerms }) => {
    return collection.filter((option) => {
        return option[field]
            .toString()
            .toLowerCase()
            .indexOf(searchTerms.toLowerCase()) >= 0
    })
}

radicalFilter({
    collection: [{ first_name: 'Bob' }, { first_name: 'Sally' }],
    field: 'first_name',
    searchTerms: 'bob',
})
```

Based on my experiences over the past couple years, the above sample is very performant. I've used it to filter 10,000 records in a `react-table` component, and it didn't break a sweat. It doesn't create any extra intermediate data structures. It is simply just `Array.prototype.filter()` which takes your array and returns a new array with matched items.

Answer (score 0):

I did this once by sending a JSON request back to the server and using Python code to do the autocomplete. It Was a little slow, but it saved sending a ton of data across.