# Auto complete text along with symbols

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a use case in which I need to take a formula which is typically like value_in_us_today + value_in_china_yesterday. All the variables (value_in_us_today ,  value_in_china_yesterday , etc ) are already available.

I'm providing a text box in which user should be able to enter text with auto complete and some operands as well. I tried jquery autocomplete but as soon as +/- is entered, auto complete stops. Is there any other way around here ? Anybody had worked on a similar case before ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript autocomplete without external library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404855/javascript-autocomplete-without-external-library)

Comment: @ObsidianAge Thanks for your comment but that doesn't solve my problem. As soon as I enter +/-  and start typing a new word, the suggestions wouldn't come.