# Filter a JavaScript array of strings matching a sequence of characters

Tags: javascript

How can I efficiently filter an array of strings matching a sequence of characters, such that characters may be matched anywhere in the string but in the order they are used?

It's a feature commonly seen in editors and IDEs to quickly filter filenames.

See an illustration of the filter in action in the attached image link.

[image: Illustration of Filter in action]

This is not a duplicate of [JavaScript autocomplete without external library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404855/javascript-autocomplete-without-external-library), because one of the requirements here is for user input "Caz" to match "Cangzhou" which is explained in the answer to this question, but not in the answers to other questions.

Comment: Not attempted to come up with a solution. if I had i would have posted it. I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Just googling "Javascript autocomplete" will give you many resources.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404855/javascript-autocomplete-without-external-library   and  
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp  for example

Comment: depending what your frameworks are, there are a bunch of options for autocomplete for both Async server based info and local info.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to google. I did after the suggestion and seeing the answer from Robby Comlissen.  But most are examples for substring matches and are filled with too much noise setting up css & html. There is none that I have yet seen that uses ES6 + the idea of building a regex to perform the match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should be pretty close. The answer tries to build a regular expression to make it so that characters are matched in the order they appear in the search term.

```js
const values = ['Brussels', 'Cairo', 'Casablanca', 'Cangzhou', 'Caracas',
    'Los Angeles', 'Osaka'];

const match = (s) => {
  const p = Array.from(s).reduce((a, v, i) => `${a}[^${s.substr(i)}]*?${v}`, '');
  const re = RegExp(p);
  
  return values.filter(v => v.match(re));
};

console.log(match('Ca'));    // Cairo, Casablanca, Cangzhou, Caracas
console.log(match('Caz'));   // Cangzhou
console.log(match('as'));    // Casablanca, Caracas
console.log(match('aa'));    // Casablanca, Caracas, Osaka
```

Answer (score 6):

This is actually simpler than it looks. Also, the currently accepted solution does not actually work consistently.

You simply need to construct a regex that accepts 0 or more characters between each character of the search string.

```
const values = ['Belgium', 'Brest', 'Britian']
const query = 'Be'

// /.*b.*e.*/
const re = RegExp(`.*${query.toLowerCase().split('').join('.*')}.*`)

// [ 'Belgium', 'Brest' ]
const matches = values.filter(v => v.toLowerCase().match(re))
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is an example for that.

To reduce error unexpected, you should limit the input value to what you want they key in.

```js
var all = ['test','string','array','example'];

function getMatch(arr, str){
  var reg = new RegExp(str.split('').join('.*'), 'i');
  
  return arr.filter(function(item) {
    if (item.match(reg)) {
      return item;
    }
  });
}

function search(value){
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = getMatch(all, value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="search(this.value)">
<br />
<span id="result"></span>
```

Answer (score -11):

This simple example uses a Regular Expression and `Array.prototype.filter()`

```js
var strings = ["Cairo", "Casablanca", "Cangzhou", "Carcas"]; // Your array of things to filter

function disp(matches) {
 
    // Displays the filtered results on the page
    var results = document.getElementById("suggestions");
    results.innerHTML = matches.join("<br>");

}

function regExpTest(inputString, regex) {
    
    // Checks to see if what the user typed matches any items in gucciArray
    return regex.test(inputString);

}

function typeKey(event) { // This function is supposed to be called whenever the user types a letter in the text box
      
    var textTyped = event.target.value; // What the user typed in the text box;

    var filter = new RegExp(textTyped.split('').join('.*'), 'i'); // Matches anything with the characters that the user typed, in order, with any characters inbetween them
  
    // Filter the array
    // Returns a new array containing the items from the old array that pass the RegExp test
    var filteredArray = strings.filter(s => regExpTest(s, filter));

    // Display the filtered results on the page
    disp(filteredArray);

}

disp(strings);
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

        Type here: <input type="text" onkeyup="typeKey(event);">
        <br>
        List of matches:
        <div id="suggestions"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

`disp` is optional. It's just for the interactive code snippet. If you want to get the values to use later, replace the last line in `typeKey` with `return newArray;`

Comment: This answer is under discussion here. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372861/whats-wrong-with-this-answer/372863#comment623587_372863